# Button to call a php function?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am new to javascript world.

I wrote a function in PHP. How do I call it when I click a button or image in html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call serverside functions you should use AJAX.

Goto http://www.w3schools.com, and take the AJAX tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You have a general missunderstanding.

PHP is serverside, HTML/JS is clientside.

so if you want to call a server method from clientside you have to execute a request to the server. in modern days this is done via an AJAX request.

Checkout Jquery ajax functions this would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to make a request to a PHP page, usually via AJAX, and then that page has to call the PHP function and return the results.