# how to show the "content" from a php variable with jquery? (it shows me the "name" itself, not the content in it)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hmm... i'm trying to use a php variable in jquery, in my edit.php : i'd like to use jquery to show the php variable, using the "rel" attribute, but it gives me the "name" of the variable, not its content.

i'm using php to retrieve the text from the xml file : (edit : one click on submit does not update the text, but 2 clicks do)

```
/* READ */
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load('edition.xml');

$_home = $dom->getElementsByTagName('home')->item(0);
$home = $_home->firstChild->nodeValue;

$_rhizo = $dom->getElementsByTagName('rhizo')->item(0);
$rhizo = $_rhizo->firstChild->nodeValue;

$_disco = $dom->getElementsByTagName('disco')->item(0);
$disco = $_disco->firstChild->nodeValue;

/* array */
$rels = array('home' => $home,
'rhizo' =>$rhizo,
'disco' =>$disco);

echo '<script>var rels = ' . json_encode($rels) . '</script>';


/* WRITE */
if ( isset($_POST['cache']) ){

    if ( isset($_POST['home']) ){
     $home = stripslashes($_POST['home']);
     $_home->firstChild->nodeValue = $home;
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['rhizo']) ){
     $rhizo = stripslashes($_POST['rhizo']);
     $_rhizo->firstChild->nodeValue = $rhizo;
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['disco']) ){
     $disco = stripslashes($_POST['disco']);
     $_disco->firstChild->nodeValue = $disco;
    }

    $dom->save('edition.xml');

}
?>
```

(the text is simply shown in a textarea, where i just put the php variable)
then i use jquery to show the content from the php variable : (edit with the array object : )

```
$('#left a').bind('click', function(){

    var text_from_link = $(this).text();

    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#textarea1').attr('name', rel);

    $('#textarea1').text(rels[''+rel+'']);//output is "$home" for example, which will retrieve the "home" part from the xml

    return false;
})
```

And this works if i double click on submit, if i just click once, the text is not updated... i'm a bit confused with that

Thanks for your help

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2145727/212218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an ajax call to do that.

Or you can write a javascript object in your HTML:

```
$rels = array('rel23' => 'Hello world');
echo '<script>var rels = ' . json_encode($rels) . '</script>';
```

Then access them with javascript:

```
alert(rels.rel23);
```

Comment: thanks El Boletaire Underave! so if i have an array in my php page, how can i use it in my jquery file? and should i use it like that : `alert(rels[0]);`? Thanks again

Comment: Well, in my example should be `alert(rels.rel23)` or `alert(rels['rel23'])`

Comment: thanks ! yeah sorry i think i was a bit tired! okay, i have a little problem : when i submit to update the text, it gives me the old text if i click `one time`. But if i double click on submit, it updates the text... i'm a bit confused, i edited the code above, would you know why and how to fix this? i tried to simulate `window.location.href("edition.php");` in the submit method after the click, but it does not change anything

Comment: Have you wrapped your jquery code with jQuery(function($){}); ??

Comment: thanks, i had to change the order and it works, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

like mentioned you will need to use ajax for this.. jQuery provides ajax and it appears you are already using it soooo....

```
if(isset($_POST["getHome"])) {
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load('edition.xml');

$_home = $dom->getElementsByTagName('home')->item(0);
$home = $_home->firstChild->nodeValue;
echo $home; // anything returned by this page will become 'data'
}
```

and

```
$(function(){

    $('a').bind('click', function(){
        $.post("mypage.php",{getHome : 1}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    })

});
```

ok assuming you have an array in your php

```
if(isset($_POST["varName"])) { // will check if the POST variable with the name 'varName' is set
  $arr = array(1,2,3); // your array
  echo json_encode($arr); // encode your output as a json string
}
```

then in your javascript

```
$(function(){

    $('a').bind('click', function(){
        $.post("mypage.php",{varName: 1}, function(data) { // the value of 1 is trivial. and is likely not needed, you can post to a page without passing any values. In which case the use if isset() in php is not required.
            var json_obj = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(json_obj); // assuming you have a console at your disposal. 
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: thanks rlemon, i have like 15 php variables at the top of the page, so ... i can't really "echo" them, can you explain me a bit about your code? Thanks

Comment: do you want to return them to the client?

Comment: Hi rlemon,thanks ok i understand a bit more. The thing is i use my own edit.php page to show the text (from the xml) and to write the text. So i have a hidden input that checks if the form was sent, in your example, it seems that i need to create another php page with the result from the XML file right? i also edited my first post, in order to explain a bit more what i'm using. It works pretty well with an array created in the php chunk of code, but the text is only updated if i click twice on submit, not if i only click "once"... and i don't have a real explanation for that

Comment: I can help you paul but I am having trouble understanding what you are doing with the limited code provided. We can possibly start a chat on this and I can help you figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: alright, thanks, i had to change the order and it works, thanks a lot for your help, Cheers!